# Strange "Delta" in MS RLE specification

Tags: algorithm, bmp

everyone.
I have BMP specification from MS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183383.aspx) and I want to know how apps should work with the 'Delta' feature: should it leave pixels after jump (5-th line in example) (and if yes, which color should it use?) or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that you should take a look [on this page](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm): it has explained example of BMP/RLE  data, including delta. In short: yes, you should to skip the pixels, because they are not important for you.